# changing database in entity framework c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

Let us consider the entity class listed as

```
public NerdDinnerEntities() : base("name=NerdDinnerEntities", "NerdDinnerEntities")
        {

            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

            OnContextCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new NerdDinnerEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public NerdDinnerEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "NerdDinnerEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

            OnContextCreated();
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new NerdDinnerEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public NerdDinnerEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "NerdDinnerEntities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }
```

and these being read as  in web config file as

```
<add name="NerdDinnerEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NerdDinner.csdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.ssdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=*;
    Initial Catalog=db;User ID=*;Password=****;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and my problem is i need to change the database name from db to db1 through code with out change in web config file..

as enitity as a class name called changedatabase() .. but i do not know how to use it...

and my another question is it possible to add a new dll in to this project and change the connectionstring meta data there by when ever the connection is opened there by it will come to that dll and change the database name only and return with that database...

Waiting for your valuable commands and sugessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyEntities : NerdDinnerEntities
{
  public MyEntities() : base(GetConnectionString())
  {
  }

  private string GetConnectionString()
  {
    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    var builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    var internalConnectionString = builder["provider connection string"].ToString();
    var newConnectionString = internalConnectionString.Replace("oldDBName", "newDBName");
    builder["provider connection string"] = newConnectionString;
    return builder.ConnectionString;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting !  i do not know where to use this code! can u say me!

Comment: If you want this change to be permanent then you can replace the connection string in the web.config file, and yes, you can do it from a dll.

Comment: ya i want it through dll... i need to create a library file in which inherits dbcontext and place this coding in it ... has i want to change anything in web.config file... give me some tips reg it

Comment: the above is my entity class since this concept is new to me i do not know how to proceed with dll ? need ur guidelines /......

Comment: In your inherited class (from NerdDinnerEntities), add this code in the parameterless constructor and call your base class constructor that gets a connection string as a paremeter

Comment: whether is dis correct as  public class a:NerdDinnerEntities(){ public class conn: base("name=NerdDinnerEntities")

Comment: {var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
var builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;
var internalConnectionString = builder["provider connection string"].ToString();
var newConnectionString = internalConnectionString.Replace("oldDBName", "newDBName");
builder["provider connection string"] = newConnectionString;
var entitiesContext = new NerdDinnerEntities(builder.ConnectionString); } }

Comment: or check this link for ur verification is iam on rightway http://pastie.org/4357655

Comment: but it is not coming inside the class which i wrote ... is it necessary to change anything in web.config file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14620/discussion-between-amiram-korach-and-gowthamanss)